# El valor no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parametro: items - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlist

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto en Asp.Net MVC y estoy creando un formulario con un `DropDownListFor` el cuál si me lista los valores pero al querer guardarlo en la BD me arroja ese error y ya llevo bastante tiempo intentando corregirlo. Ya intenté de todo y no encuentro en dónde estoy mal.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Éste es el código de mi Modelo (`PerfilViewModel`)

```
public class PerfilViewModel
{
    public int? idPerfil { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public int idEstatus { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Estatus { get; set; }
}
```

Éste es el código de mi Controller (`PerfilesController`)

```
OrganizacionEntities2 db = new OrganizacionEntities2();

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            PerfilViewModel vm = new PerfilViewModel();

            if (Session["Usuario"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Estatus = db.catEstatus.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = x.descripcion,
                    Value = x.idEstatus.ToString()
                }).ToList();

                return View(vm);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(PerfilViewModel vm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (OrganizacionEntities2 db = new OrganizacionEntities2())
                    {
                        db.catPerfiles.Add(new catPerfiles()
                        {
                            descripcion = vm.descripcion,
                            idEstatus = vm.idEstatus.idEstatus
                        });
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        ViewBag.successMessage = "Estatus agregado con exito";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewBag.successMessage = "Ocurrio un error, reintente por favor";
                }
            }
            return View(vm);
        }
```

Éste es el código de mi Vista (`Create`)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Perfiles", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="Create">
        <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputDescripcion" class="form-control-label mt-3 ml-5">Descripción:</label>
                    <input type="text" style="width:1130px" class="form-control ml-5" id="descripcion" name="descripcion">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEstatus" class="form-control-label ml-5">Estatus:</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idEstatus, new SelectList(ViewBag.Estatus, "Value", "Text"))
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default mb-3 ml-5">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mb-3">Crear</button>
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

Aquí está el error completo:

**Descripción:** Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

**Detalles de la excepción:** System.ArgumentNullException: El valor no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parámetro: items

**Error de código fuente:**

```
Línea 54:                     <div class="form-group">
Línea 55:                         <label for="inputEstatus" class="form-control-label ml-5">Estatus:</label>
**Línea 56:                         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idEstatus, new SelectList(Model.Estatus, "Value", "Text"))**
Línea 57:                     </div>
Línea 58:                 </div>
```

**Seguimiento de la pila:**

```
[ArgumentNullException: El valor no puede ser nulo.
Nombre del parámetro: items]
   System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, String dataValueField, String dataTextField, String dataGroupField, IEnumerable selectedValues, IEnumerable disabledValues, IEnumerable disabledGroups) +169
   System.Web.Mvc.SelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, String dataValueField, String dataTextField) +27
   ASP._Page_Views_Perfiles_Create_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\Monserrat\Desktop\AdministraZion\AdministraZion\Views\Perfiles\Create.cshtml:56
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +73
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9849569
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
```

Comment: esta propiedad `public int? idPerfil { get; set; }` en la base de datos la tienes definida para que reciba **null** ? esta propiedad no vendría siendo la clave primaria de la tabla ?

Comment: Hola, indica por favor el error completo.

Comment: En la BD tengo el idPerfil como not null, ya busque lo que significa int? y me dice que es permitir null, así que ya lo deje sólo como int pero sigue con ese error. @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta con el error completo @RafaelAcosta

Comment: @MonsePM, lo que dice el error es que en alguna de tu variables esta llegando un null te aconsejo que realices un debug y valides cual es , solo es por eso que aparece el error, la que es de tipo string  no tiene problema ya que esa puede llegar null o vacia

Answer (score 2):

Si te das cuenta, después de guardar el registro en la Acción `[HttpPost] Create()`, **vuelves a ir a la Vista Create.cshtml** --> **`return View(vm);`**

Cuando la Vista `Create.cshtml` se vuelve a cargar, **ya no existe** la variable **`ViewBag.Estatus`** en el nuevo contexto. Esto es así porque el **ViewBag** solo tiene persistencia en un único Request.

Por todo esto, cuando la Vista `Create.cshtml` vuelve a cargar el `DropDownListFor()` con el contenido del `ViewBag.Estatus`, este es Null y te lanza el error.

Para solucionarlo, vuelve a cargar el `ViewBag.Estatus` con los datos antes de hacer el `return View(vm);`.

El código sería el así:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PerfilViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                using (OrganizacionEntities2 db = new OrganizacionEntities2())
                {
                    db.catPerfiles.Add(new catPerfiles()
                    {
                        descripcion = vm.descripcion,
                        idEstatus = vm.idEstatus.idEstatus
                    });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    ViewBag.successMessage = "Estatus agregado con exito";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.successMessage = "Ocurrio un error, reintente por favor";
            }
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Aquí vuelves a cargar los datos del DropDownListFor() //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ViewBag.Estatus = db.catEstatus.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.descripcion,
            Value = x.idEstatus.ToString()
        }).ToList();

        return View(vm);
    }
```